# How to require dependent drop down whenever there are options to choose from in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a form with a dependent drop-down. Currently, I have it set so that the second drop-down only appears if there are options available in it, otherwise is hidden. What I am having trouble with is that, whenever you choose a primary(Work Area) option that has a secondary(Station) drop-down, you can submit the form without having selected an option from the dependent (secondary) drop-down, which is supposed to be required whenever there are options in it.

How can I modify this so that the dependent drop-down is required whenever it appears?

**models.py**

```
class WorkArea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Station(models.Model):
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="stations")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, help_text="Work Area", related_name="work_area")
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, help_text="Station", related_name="stations", blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.none()

        if 'work_area' in self.data:
            try:
                work_area_id = int(self.data.get('work_area'))
                self.fields['station_number'].queryset = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['station_number'].queryset = self.instance.work_area.stations.order_by('name')
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    enter_without_exit = None
    exit_without_enter = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form handling...

def load_stations(request):
    work_area_id = request.GET.get('work_area')
    stations = Station.objects.filter(work_area_id=work_area_id).order_by('name')
    return render(request, 'operations/station_number_dropdown_options.html', {'stations': stations})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('ajax/load-stations/', views.load_stations, name='ajax_load_stations'),
]
```

**station_number_dropdown_options.html**

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for station in stations %}
<option value="{{ station.pk }}">{{ station.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried adding this to forms.py (Box Assembly is one of the options that does have stations)

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        work_area = cleaned_data['work_area']
        station = cleaned_data['station_number']
        if work_area in ('Box Assembly', 'Other) and station is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a station")
```

But, when running on debugger I see this, yet the form does not raise any errors. Is there something I'm not catching?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WorkArea is not a string. You should compare to the property `name`.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    work_area = cleaned_data['work_area']
    station = cleaned_data['station_number']

    if work_area.name == 'Box Assembly' and station is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must select a station")
```